# Dry cleaning and Electronics?

Tags: integrated-circuit, short-circuit

I'm thinking of embedding a circuit into a jacket that I have, and I was wondering whether I could dry clean it with the circuit still attached to it. I read that dry cleaning could potentially dissolve items like plastic pens and was wondering if it could dissolve the PCB or the chip's shell...

Answer (score 2):

PWB is an epoxy resin fiberglass mix and plastic chips are encased in an epoxy resin polymer mix both similar to epoxy adhesive which are category 4 = not recommended with Perchloroethylene , the dry cleaning fluid commonly used.  Perhaps something else can be used. http://www.beaconadhesives.com/epxchmresis.html

Answer (score 2):

I use acetone, trichloroethylene and perchloroethene to clean prototype boards from solder remains. Often the liquid goes on chips and components, and in 20 years I never had a single problem with components or PCB itself.